# Does Spark cache updates automatically at any intervals with the new value of data?

Tags: caching, cassandra, pyspark

I am using pyspark and cassandra, and caching the data using cache() function.
I want to know if the cache updates automatically everytime the data is updated in cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

RDD's are immutable, so once an RDD is created, it's contents cannot change.  If an RDD is created from a Cassandra table, the RDD is a snapshost of the data that was in Cassandra at the time the RDD was created.

When you tell spark to cache an RDD, you are telling spark to reuse the contents of that RDD rather than create a new RDD the next time you use it in a spark action.

If you want the data in the RDD to be refreshed from Cassandra each time you use it, then you wouldn't want to cache it.  Or you could use the spark unpersist() function when you wanted to refresh the data from Cassandra.  This will cause spark to re-read all the Cassandra data into a new RDD the next time it is used.

So it would not read just the rows that have changed since your last read, but all of them.  This will greatly reduce performance if the table is large, but you would get the latest data.

Comment: Thanks Jim, this helped :)
One more thing.. I want to read data from Cassandra in real time for Spark computation, but I don't want to use Kafka or Flume as it may cause Zookeeper overhead. 
Is there any other way you can suggest to have the functionality?

Comment: Real time analysis with spark would typically be done with spark streaming.  Incoming data is received and processed by spark in micro-batches and the results are then saved to Cassandra.   So the data source wouldn't be from Cassandra in that case.

Comment: My Architecture is Cassandra containing data and Spark analyzing it.
So do I need to have Kafka in between Cassandra and Spark?

Comment: I don't think Kafka is normally used between Spark and Cassandra.  If you want to read newly inserted data from Cassandra into Spark, then you would structure your Cassandra data to partition the new data into chucks that you could read into spark at regular intervals for processing.

Comment: After alot of analysis we came to a conclusion that we will be using kafka or Fluentd for spark streaming, will do the analytics over that and will store the result in Cassandra and then will query Cassandra to get the near real time data.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a reasonable approach.